# Как изменить ширину кнопки когда окно приложения не в fullscreen?

Tags: java, javafx, scene-builder

Делаю приложение на JavaFX и Scene Builder

Имеется класс Main который запускает приложение и вызывает контроллер

В контроллере имеется кнопка с prefWidth 45 и высотой - 90

Кнопка завернута в Stack Pane, который в свою очередь завернут в AnchorPane

**Как можно изменить ширину кнопки на 25, когда приложение находится НЕ в fullsceen режиме, и наоборот: когда окно программы в fullscreen - ширина кнопки 
 - 45?**

**Возможно ли сделать адаптивность размера кнопки под размер окна приложения?**

**Main:**

```
public class Main extends Application {      

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  launch(args); 
 }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

  try {

  Parent root = 
 FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/card/resources/fxml/card.fxml"));
  Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1600, 600);
  primaryStage.setScene(scene);


  scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css")
  .toExternalForm());
  primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
  primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
  primaryStage.setResizable(true);

  primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("card/resources/logo-icon.png"));
  primaryStage.show();

    //adding resize and drag primary stage
    ResizeHelper.addResizeListener(primaryStage);

  //assign ALT+ENTER to maximize window
  final KeyCombination kb = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.ENTER, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);
  scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
      if (kb.match(event)) {
        primaryStage.setMaximized(!primaryStage.isMaximized());
        primaryStage.setResizable(true);

      }
    }
  });

} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

}

}
```

**Controller:**

```
@FXML  private AnchorPane anchorRow;
@FXML  private StackPane hBoxCat0;
@FXML  private Button btnPalette;

@FXML
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

 }
}
```